# Converting the elements of an array of interger into a single integer in Java

Tags: java, arrays, type-conversion, int

I would like to convert the elements of an array of integers into a single integer. Note that I haven't learn the join or number methods in class yet so they cannot be use for this program.

For example, {1, 2, 3} would become 123.

Here is my thought of process:

1. Convert the first element of the array into a String
2. Concatenate the remaining elements
3. Use `Integer.parseInt()` to convert the String back to an integer

Can anyone confirm I am doing this the right way or suggest an alternative way?

Also, by curiosity, how could we compare the elements of two integer arrays without using the class Arrays?

Comment: Hi, you want to sum them ?
Or you want to convert element of integer to string and concatanate them and parse the result value to int ?

Comment: If the assignment doesn't specify **how** you need to do this conversion, then there are a few much easier ways to do it. The first one is `return 1;` - it converts any array to a single integer. The second one links the result to the array to a degree: `return array.length;`. If your assignment does say how, then you forgot to mention that in your question.

Comment: @MykhailoMoskura No, I do not want to sum them, just concatenate them. For example, {1, 2, 3} would become 123.

Comment: See [`String::concat`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/String.html#concat(java.lang.String)).

Comment: Provide further detail as edits to your Question rather than as Comments.

Comment: @ErwinBolwidt By curiosity, how could we compare the elements of two integer arrays without using the class Arrays?

Answer (score 1):

This is how it can be done using java 8:

```
 final int[] array = new int[]{1,2,3};
   final String result = IntStream
                    .of(array)
                    .boxed()
                    .map(String::valueOf)
                    .collect(Collectors.joining());
   final int intResult = Integer.parseInt(result);
```

I also would add check if array contains one element for example

```
 public int arrayOfIntsAsSingleInt ( final int[] array){
            if (Objects.isNull(array) || array.length == 0) {
                throw new IllegalArgumentsException("array could not be null or empty")
            } else if (array.length == 1) {
                return array[0];
            }
            return convertArraysofIntAsSingleInt(array);
        }
```

We can compare two integers by writing custom Comparator or

invoke Integer.compareTo(anotherInteger) method

Comment: I would like to compare the elements inside the array not integers

Comment: Why do you need it ?
The problem what you want to solve?

Comment: I am just curious

Comment: What do you mean by inside an array ?

Comment: I want to compare the elements inside an array (numbers inside the array) such that {1, 2, 3} and {1, 2, 3} would return true while {4, 5, 6} and {6, 5, 4}

Comment: So in this example you are telling to check if elements in two arrays are equal , right?

Comment: This is good case when you need to compare two arrays if their elements are equal
You can write your own method which accepts two arrays as arguments 
Then check if their length is the same , if not then return false
Then iterate in cycle and check if(array1[k] != array2[k]) return false ; else true

Answer (score 0):

> Can anyone confirm I am doing this the right way

If you input is valid,your method is right to do what you want. @Mykhailo Moskura give a method use Java 8 Stream API to join string.

> suggest an alternative way?

if you element in your input array within a certain range(0,9) and the first element must not be 0,you can try this code:
        int[] inputs = {1, 2, 3};

```
    int factor = 0;
    int result = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++) {
        result = inputs[i] + factor * 10;
        factor = result;
    }

    System.out.println(result);
```

the output is: 123

> compare two array not use Arrays

Assume not use any tool,you can use two map to compare two arrays:

```
public static boolean compareArray(int[] arr1, int[] arr2) {
        if (arr1.length != arr2.length) {
            return false;
        }

        Map<Integer, Integer> map1 = new HashMap<>();
        Map<Integer, Integer> map2 = new HashMap<>();
        for (int arr : arr1) {
            Integer times = map1.getOrDefault(arr, 0);
            map1.put(arr, times + 1);
        }
        for (int arr : arr2) {
            Integer times = map2.getOrDefault(arr, 0);
            map2.put(arr, times + 1);
        }

        for (Integer key : map1.keySet()) {
            if (!map1.get(key).equals(map2.get(key))) {
                return false;
            }
        }
        return true;
    }
```

Comment: Hi , it can be done with less code just iterating through array.length and comparing them using index from cycle

Comment: compare two arrays:array1={1,2,3,2},array2={2,1,2,3},they are the same array,can we solve this?

Comment: Same array is array which have the same order of elements

Comment: Not actually O(n) , if would be collision worst case would be like O(n^2) , you have not mentioned this case because big o notation is worst case